# How to order a numbered list in descending order?

Tags: microsoft-word, sorting, numbering

When using a numbered list in Word, how can I have it order in descending order (ie. 10., 9., 8., 7., ...) ?

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/generate-a-descending-order-numbered-list-in-word/696

Comment: Also http://word.tips.net/T001759_Reverse_Numbered_Lists.html

Answer (score 1):

A quick way of doing it is:

1. Copy your list.

[image: Highlight and Copy List]

2. Paste your list as 'Keep Text Only'.

[image: Paste as 'Keep Text Only']

3. Highlight the newly pasted list and click on the Sort button located in the Paragraph group on the Home Tab.
4. Sort Text by Number Descending.

[image: Highlight the list and Sort by Number Descending]

End Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetely Word is unable to do so. Standard Word-Tables only provide limited, basic functionality.
Nevertheless you can copy your table into Excel and sort it there like this:
[image]
After that copy your table back to Word.
You can also embed an Excel-Table into you Word application if you need advanced functionality (with less clicks) like this:
[image]

P.S.: Sorry for the german Screenshots

Answer (score -1):

- Highlight the text you wish to sort
- Click 'table' on the top of the screen
- Click 'sort' in the dropdown menu
- Under 'sort by', set the parameters to 'paragraphs', 'numbers', and 'descending'
- Click OK....

You should be descending now.

Comment: These buttons / context menus / options are not available in Microsoft Word.